# methode $_POST is empty php

Tags: php, html, css

The problem is $_POST["nomuniv"] &  cod $_POST["coduniv"], they are empty and I do not understand why despite all of input names being correct.

webpage1:

```
<style type="text/css">
    input[type=text],button{
        width: 100%;padding: 12px 20px;

        display: inline-block;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 4px;`enter code here`
        box-sizing: border-box;  
    }
    ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        font-size: 13px;
        color: #000;
    }

</style>
<?php
include 'fonctionUnivesrite.php';
$array = selectFCT();//selection data from DB
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    ?>
    <form method="post" action="../universites/supprimer_universite.php?id=<?php echo $array[$i][0]; ?>">
        <table class="table table-striped " style="width: 70%;" align="center">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 5%;" ><?php echo $i; ?> </td>
                <td style="width: 30%;">
                    <input type="text" name="nomuniv" id="nomuniv" placeholder="<?php echo $array[$i][1]; ?>">
                </td>
                <td style="width: 20%;">
                    <input type="text" name="coduniv" id="coduniv" placeholder="<?php echo $array[$i][2]; ?>"  >
                </td>
                <td style="width: 10%;">
                    <input type="submit" name="modifier" class="btn btn-warning" value="Modifier">
                </td>
                <td style="width: 10%;">
                    <input type="submit" name="supprimer" class="btn btn-danger"  value="Supprimer">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </table>
</form>
```

---

webpage2:../universites/supprimer_universite.php

```
include './fonctionUnivesrite.php';


if (isset($_GET["id"])) {

    if(isset($_POST["modifier"])){
        try {
            echo $_GET["id"]." nom ".$_POST["nomuniv"]." cod ".$_POST["coduniv"];
            modifierFCT($_GET["id"],$_POST["nomuniv"],$_POST["coduniv"]);
            //echo $_GET["id"]." nom ".$_POST["nomuniv"]." cod ".$_POST["coduniv"];
        } catch (Exception $exc) {
            echo "Error : " . $exc->getMessage();
        }
    }

    elseif(isset($_POST["supprimer"])) {
        try {
            deletFCT($_GET["id"]);
        } catch (Exception $exc) {
            echo "Error : " . $exc->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is simple , 
You didnt add a value attribute to the input fileds ,
In webpage 1 
Try to add inside

```
<input value=" your php code " />
```

Since when you use `$_POST` it will access the value , according to the name

Comment: so I do that                                                                                                                      
                    <input type="text" name="nomuniv" id="nomuniv" placeholder="<?php echo $array[$i][1]; ?>" value="<?php echo $array[$i][1]; ?>">

Comment: @mahditrad What do you mean by `</input>`? That's not valid HTML.

Comment: @Barmar sorry my mistake , you cant do this he is right .. anyway thank you